# Mycelium - more than one unused Bitcoin HD account

Tags: wallet, bip32-hd-wallets, mycelium-wallet

Why can't I have more than one unused Bitcoin HD Account? What if I want to use a Bitcoin mixer that allows for 5 destination addresses?

Answer (score 1):

You can have multiple addresses on one account.

Accounts are not a feature of the Bitcoin protocol, they are a feature created by some wallets to help you organise your money.